# C++ Builder Firemonkey effects on bitmaps

Tags: c++, graphics, bitmap, firemonkey

The Firemonkey platform for C++ Builder has some nice graphical effects that one can use on a TImage control.

Is it possible to use some of these effects on a bitmap in memory?
If so, how is that done?

Comment: Have you looked at the `TBitmap` class and its `Canvas` property? What effects are you interested in, exactly?  Please be more specific.

Comment: Lets say the Sepia effect.

Comment: I may be wrong, but from reading Embarcadero's documentation, I believe FMX's image effects are only usable on UI controls, not on say a `TBitmap` in memory ([unless it is the `TImageControl.Bitmap`, apparently](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Using_FireMonkey_Image_Effects#Applying_Multiple_Effects_to_a_Picture)).